# Nothing happens for either input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a feeling I've made a silly mistake somewhere but at nearly 2am I just can't see it...

Here's the code in question. It is part of a function:

```
running = True
while (running): 
    playerName = input("Please enter your first name \n").title()
    print ("You have entered '%s' as your name. Is this correct?"%playerName)
    playerNameChoice = input("Enter 'Y' for Yes or 'N' for No.\n").upper()
    if(playerNameChoice == "Y"):
        break
        #The following randomly selects Card 1 for the computer
        randomComputerCard = random.choice(availableCards)
        if randomComputerCard in (Queen,King,Jack,Ace):
            randomComputerCard = 10
        else:
            randomComputerCard = randomComputerCard

        randomComputerCard2 = random.choice(availableCards)
        if randomComputerCard2 in (Queen,King,Jack,Ace):
            randomComputerCard2 = 10
        else:
            randomComputerCard2 = randomComputerCard2

        print ("%i"%randomComputerCard)
        print ("%i"%randomComputerCard2)
        print ("TEST OVER")



    elif(playerNameChoice == "N"):
     continue
```

During testing when I enter Y when prompted to enter either Y or N nothing happens, it just continues the loop when it should actually break. However when I enter N it does exactly what it's meant to and continues the loop. Sorry if this is a waste of a question, but I actually have no idea what I've done incorrectly.

Thanks in advance as always! :)

*EDIT: The variable availableCards has already been defined.*

Comment: You have a `break` where there should not be one

Comment: @user2864740 thanks, I thought I needed it to stop it from continuously looping. Thank you for correcting me and thanks for editing the question title too, it'll prevent the question from getting a couple vote downs I would assume. Thanks a load! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the 'break' at line 7. That's causing your code to exit prematurely.

Comment: @R Samuel ah, I put it in because I thought I needed it to break the loop so that it didn't continue to loop. Will give it a try now, thank you very much!

Comment: As soon as execution reaches, the `break` statement, you will break out of your loop. Try moving that break statement somewhere else.

Comment: @R Samuel I understand, thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question and give me the advice! Ticked as answer! :)